# File Upload in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I need to update a file which is on a remote server, using Silverlight and C#.
I created the file on the current machine and after that I tried to upload it using [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/file-upload-in-silverlight/). It returned no error, but it doesn't upload my file either.

Could you help me?

this is the ashx code

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="receiver" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

public class receiver : IHttpHandler {

   public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string filename = context.Request.QueryString["DB.xml"].ToString();

    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(context.Server.MapPath("~/CLientBin" + filename)))
    {
        SaveFile(context.Request.InputStream, fs);
    }
}

private void SaveFile(Stream stream, FileStream fs)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
 }
}
```

and this is the c# code:

```
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Multiselect = false;
        dlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|PNG Images (*.png)|*.png";

        bool? retval = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (retval != null && retval == true)
        {
            try
            {
                UploadFile(dlg.File.Name, dlg.File.OpenRead());
                titlu.Text = dlg.File.Name;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            titlu.Text = "No file selected...";
        }
    }

    private void UploadFile(string fileName, Stream data)
    {
        UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder("http://ganduri.elementfx.com/Handler.ashx");
        ub.Query = string.Format("filename={0}", fileName);

        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        c.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            PushData(data, e.Result);
            e.Result.Close();
            data.Close();
        };
        c.OpenWriteAsync(ub.Uri);
    }

    private void PushData(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Writed");
    }
```

I have also checked the permissions to the ClientBin folder and are read/write permissions
When I run this code it shows me the "Writed" messageBox, but if I look in the server, the file  isn't anywhere.
I have set a breakpoint in af ashx file functions and id doesn't reach any of them.

Comment: I don't think we can help you without source code...

Comment: Extra tip: note that the example accepts any file name which can get you in a lot of trouble when someone starts passing `"../../somename"`

Comment: Throw a breakpoint into the Receiver.ashx page. That'll tell you if it's getting called. And then step through the code, until you see what's going wrong. Pretty basic troubleshooting.

Comment: "I took something from <somelink>, changed it, used it from my code (that I'm not going to show you) and it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?" is very hard to use to help you. Please edit your post and provide details on your exact code, or your question will probably be closed as "not a real question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you need check upload folder for existence, and write access rights